# How to receive a message with TidIRC in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, message, pascal, irc

I have the following code so far:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
FIRC.Host:= '192.168.1.48';
FIRC.Port := 61289;
FIRC.Username:= 'test';
FIRC.Nickname:= 'Test';
FIRC.RealName:= 'TEst';
FIRC.Connect;
FIRC.Join('#Test');
end;
```

And it will connect fine, but I cannot find on google how to actually receive a message on the channel. How can that be done?

Answer (score 3):

`TIdIRC` has `OnPrivateMessage` and `OnNotice` events (amongst many other events).

Comment: I am very new to Delphi. How could you implement one of these for a general message to every one?

Comment: Did you look at the events yet? Did you assign handlers to them yet?  `OnPrivateMessage` has `ANickname`, `AHost`, `ATarget`, and `AMessage` parameters.  `OnNotice` has `ANickname`, `AHost`, `ATarget`, and `ANotice` parameters.  What problem are you having in using them?

Comment: I cant find any good documentation or examples for using them.

Comment: You assign handlers to those events (you can use the Object Inspector for that), and then use the event's `AMessage` and `ANotice` parameters as needed. They contain the text messages you are looking for. Their `ANickname` and `AHost` parameters tell you the user/host who sent the messages.