# Simple Delphi/Pascal IRC client

Tags: delphi, client, pascal, irc

I have looked for forever on google on how to make a Delphi IRC client.
But to no Avail, and being new to the language of Pascal has not helped my endeavors. All I need is code demonstrating how to connect to an IRC server on a channel, and receive anything sent on just that channel(no private messages).

Thanks

Comment: Delphi ships with Indy pre-installed, and Indy has a `TIdIRC` client component with many methods including `Join()`, and many events including `OnNotice`, `OnPrivateMessage`. `OnTopic`, etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to receive a message with TidIRC in Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144263/how-to-receive-a-message-with-tidirc-in-delphi)

Comment: http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdIRC.html

Comment: Yes, I am new to pascal and some actual code examples would be helpful. I have seen all the documentation above. But you can't add 2 + 2 without knowing how to add, so to speak. Any further help would be appericated

Comment: learn from sources of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_IRC

Comment: "fpcircbot"  I feel lucky -> http://svn.freepascal.org/svn/fpcprojects/fpcircbot/

Answer (score 1):

I one wrote one: [RoIRC](http://yoy.be/ro.html) and open sourced it, but that site apparently doesn't allow open access to its SVN to non-members, so I'll put it up on github sometimes soon. Keep an eye out [here](https://github.com/stijnsanders?tab=repositories)

Comment: there also is old one - VisualIRC, once it even challenged mIRC status :-)

Comment: It's here: https://github.com/stijnsanders/ro#ro